# Tuleap - Site admin mail address

Tags: email, tuleap

How do I change the default mail address for siteadmin? I tried to change from GUI mode, but it's not working. Please provide the proper path to change the admin mail address.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it directly in the DB:

```
UPDATE user SET mail="" WHERE user_name = 'admin';
```

Comment: I think this is how I did it. You could use the GUI though, if you know how to read system mail.